# Attach values to one table from a differently shaped table

Tags: spss, pspp

So I have a data set collected from beekeeper surveys that looks something like this:

```
[Table 1]
 ID | Crop | Year | Hives | HoneyP | CropP |
----+------+------+-------+--------+-------+
  1      2   2014    2391        .       .
  2      4   2008     136        .       .
  3     12   2019   12346        .       .

         |                    |
         V   (and so on...)   V
```

I also have a spreadsheet of crop prices over a time series, e.g.

```
[Table 2]
Year | Crop1 | Crop2 |
-----+-------+-------+
2008   $2.56   $6.45                    
2009   $2.42   $6.64                    ->
2010   $2.69   $6.68   (and more crops) ->
2011   $2.62   $7.05                    ->
...
```

Is it possible in PSPP/SPSS to iterate over the observations in Table 1 and insert values from Table 2 into the `CropP` variable based on the year and crop identifier?
This is what I'm imagining, in pseudo-code:

```
for each obs:
    obs.CropP = Table2[obs.Year][obs.Crop]
```

I also have other attributes I want to add in to the observations (e.g. price index), but they're all one dimensional and could be entered manually if necessary; if I can programmatically add in a crop's price in the survey year, it would save a lot of time and trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reshaping instead of iterating.
Assuming you've read both tables into SPSS, and the datasets are called `table1` and `table2` - follow these two steps:

First you need to reshape the crop prices data to fit the main dataset:

```
dataset activate table2.
varstocases /make cropPR from crop1 to cropX/index=crop(cropPR).
*your crop index now is a string like "crop3" and needs to be turned into a number.
compute crop=char.substr(crop,5,5).
alter type crop (f5).
sort cases by year crop.
```

Now this table is ready to attach to your main data.

```
dataset activate table1.
sort cases by year crop.
match files /file=* /table=table1 /by year crop.
exe.
```